# How to stop plackup

Tags: dancer, plack

I'm trying to develop web pages for the first time, so please bear with me. I'm following the tutorial explained here- https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Dancer2/lib/Dancer2/Tutorial.pod

I ran plackup to start the application using `plackup app.psgi`. When I loaded localhost:5000 I saw that the webpage had few missing fields so I stopped plackup using `Ctrl+Z`.

Now when I use `plackup app.psgi`, I get the error-

```
failed to listen to port 5000: Address already in use at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/HTTP/Server/PSGI.pm line 103.
```

When I go to localhost:5000, the page shows it is loading but nothing appears.

How do I close/exit plackup gracefully? Is there any other to start and stop Dancer2 applications?

Answer (score -1):

`Ctrl+Z` doesn't stop an application, it's paused. Use `Ctrl+C` to stop it.

You may also start Plackup as `plackup -r app.psgi` to automatically reload source files as you change them.